# How to prevent dropdown closing on selecting date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox in dropdown list for selecting date range but when select date that dropdown closes and again i have to open dropdown and select another date.....
Here is my code :

```
<ul class="wrapper" style="z-index: 1">
<li><button style="background: #ededed;">Transactions</button>
<ul id="dropdown" class="content" style="z-index: 1">
    <li><a id="a" href="#">Today's Transactions</a></li>
     <li><a id="b" href="#">Last 7 Days Transactions</a></li>
     <li><a id="c" href="#">Last 30 Days Transactions</a></li>
     <li><a>Select Custom Date <br><br>
     <div style="margin-top: -20px">
     <date-picker todateid="endDate" fromdateid="startDate"></date-picker>
      <span>From:</span>
      <span style="margin-left: 77px">To:</span><br>
      <input type="text" name="start_date" id="startdate" class="custom-date" readonly="" >
       <span class="dash">-</span>
       <input type="text" name="end_date" id="enddate" class="custom-date" readonly="">
       <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearCalender()" style="height: 25px; width: 50px; margin-left: 125px; margin-top: 5px;">
       <input type="button" id="d" href="#" value="OK">
    </div></a>
  </li><a>
  <input type="button" name="closeBtn" class="button-trans" value="Close">
  </a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Datepicker Popups calender to Choose date.
    $(function() {
        $("#startdate").datepicker({ maxDate: 0,minDate: '-3m',yearRange: "2015:2015"});
        // Pass the user selected date format.
        $("#format").change(function() 
        {
            $("#enddate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#enddate").datepicker({ maxDate: 0,minDate: '-3m',yearRange: "2015:2015"});
        // Pass the user selected date format.
        $("#format").change(function() 
        {
            $("#startdate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());         
        });
    });
});
```

Jquery :
 jquery-ui-1.11.0.js

How can prevent datepicker from closing dropdown?

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VejNav

Comment: Can you provide fiddle/plunker?

Comment: can you give some code?

Comment: For specifying date range there should be different date picker controls  available in bootstrap. Give it a try.

Comment: Post your some code so we can help you. And to select date you can use. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Comment: you are using bootstrap droupdown

Answer (score 1):

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/4jy9131y/4/

```
 $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following way: Use `onSelect` and make `datepicker` `inline`

```
$(function() {
        $("#startdate").datepicker({ maxDate: 0,minDate: '-3m',yearRange: "2015:2015",
        onSelect: function() {       
           $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;                               
        },
        onClose: function() {
           $(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
        }});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qo0Lt4w/1/)**

It will close when you click outside else not.

**Edit:**

Use following JQuery will work for you.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').css('display','block');
});

$('#d').click(function(){
    $('.content').css('display','none');
});

$('#closeBtn').click(function(){
    $('.content').css('display','none');
});
```

**[Updated Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qo0Lt4w/3/)**

Comment: @HemangiPatil check my edited answer. I will close when you click outside else not.

Comment: Datepicker working well but when selecting date,dropdown closes...and i dont want to close dropdown while selecting date